# C++ code undefined reference to function when using shared library

Tags: c++, c, g++, shared-libraries

[image: compiler output]

I am trying to compile a simple c++ program that calls some functions from the NDPI C library.  When compiling using the shared library (.so file) it can't find some of the functions in the library (like set_ndpi_flow_malloc) but seems to be able to find another function called set_ndpi_malloc.

Note: I believe the functions it can't find were newly added to the library when it updated from version 1.8 to 2.0, but the library files I am using were all compiled from source of version 2.0.

**Strangely when I compile using the static library (.a) it has no problem finding these functions.**

See the image linked above to see the compiler output each time and the code.
The two compile attempts were made within a minute of each other and nothing was changed except for one line in the makefile to compile with the static library instead of the shared library.

### Update

This has been identified as an issue with the library not exporting all the symbols.

See the issue on github here: https://github.com/ntop/nDPI/issues/459

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: You seem to have a space after `-L`

Comment: @VTT I removed it and it didn't make a difference but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin I just tried doing it with and without -lndpi https://i.imgur.com/cUofcCH.png

Comment: Then could you please say `nm -D ~/ndpi/precompiled/ndpi/lib/libndpi.a | more` and look up those missing symbols in the output?

Comment: Maybe, even something like `nm -D ~/ndpi/precompiled/ndpi/lib/libndpi.a | grep "set_ndpi_flow_"` would be simpler to take a look at.

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin wow thanks, so I did   nm libndpi.a --demangle and compared the output to that of the same command but for libndpi.so and this was the result https://i.imgur.com/IrNuXUe.png  (static on left, shared on right) so it seems like for the shared library set_ndpi_flow_free is local (hence the lowercase t) and set_ndpi_free is global (hence the capital T).  For the static library both functions are global.  So now I guess I should look into why the shared library made the function local only.

Comment: Yeah, I see, you expanded on `nm` usage and this showed a difference. Shall I re-post my suggestion as an answer or would you prefer to dig the library further and post a self-answer later?

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin feel free to make your comment a separate answer if you'd like, I'm going to investigate the root cause of this and I will either accept your answer or create my own based on my findings.

Comment: @DanielE Thanks for your kind permit. I elaborated my thoughts a little bit more and posted it as a separate answer. I hope you'll find it acceptable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some effort to reproduce your steps.

1. [Clone](https://github.com/ntop/nDPI) (download/unpack) the library source from their Github
2. Enter the source directory of the library
3. `./autogen.sh` (as per `README.md`, also: `libpcap-dev` package is needed to be installed in the system)
4. `./configure` (as per `README.md`)
5. `make` (as per `README.md`)
6. Create a file in the home directory called `test.cpp` and place your code there (however, I think that include statement shall be reworded as simply `#include "ndpi_api.h"`)
7. `g++ -c -O3 -Wall -I ./src/include ~/test.cpp` (as per your wish)
8. `g++ -O3 -Wall -o test test.o -L ./lib -lndpi` (as per your wish)

So, indeed, there are undefined symbols in this case.
I used `nm -gC ./lib/libndpi.so` to read the symbol list and didn't find
`set_ndpi_flow_malloc` and `set_ndpi_flow_free`. Not mentioned in either way.

I then inspected `./src/include/ndpi_api.h` and `./src/lib/ndpi_main.c` and couldn't wrap my head around what might have been wrong there. Everything seemed to be OK since these two functions were implemented and defined similar to their counterparts without *_flow_*. Nevertheless, the difference certainly exists and could be observed in `./libndpi.sym` file.
As you might see, `set_ndpi_malloc` and `set_ndpi_free` are listed there whilst their *_flow_* counterparts are not.

So, I deleted the library source and followed the steps **1** and **2** one more time. Then I added these two lines to `./libndpi.sym` just after non-*_flow_* function names:

```
set_ndpi_flow_malloc
set_ndpi_flow_free
```

Next I had to proceed with the steps **3**-**8** and the last one turned to be successful.
Also, `nm -gC ./lib/libndpi.so` shows the symbols of interest just fine.

I may suppose that forgetting to add the symbol names to `.sym` file is some sort of mistake. Here is the [commit](https://github.com/ntop/nDPI/commit/4300208642e0ccd4d945a25e738b65d019b2cc30#diff-414f7c417eb4be3896935c36a0972eb7) by *Vito Piserchia*. Perhaps it would be better if you contacted that person or, maybe, [lucaderi](https://github.com/lucaderi), who makes the impression of an avid contributor, to tell them about the issue with the symbols. As you may learn from `libndpi.sym` [commit history](https://github.com/ntop/nDPI/commits/dev/libndpi.sym), they often "add missing symbols", etc.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you so much you have been extremely helpful!!  I followed your steps and verified that my test program works now.  I did submit an issue here https://github.com/ntop/nDPI/issues/459 and I will add more information to the issue now that you have identified the cause of the problem.